Use SessionId from request body instead of a cookie in .NET Core 8
We had an old project using the .NET Framework. It's an "API with state", where state is handled using SessionID, that is one of fields in the request body (json).
When user starts flow, no sessionId is sent, session is created by the backend and returned in the response, and then used in the following requests.
We achieved that using SessionManager: ISessionIDManager, IHttpModule in the .NET framework which is defined as the sessionIDManagerType in web.config.
Now, in .NET 8, I cannot find anything similar to sessionIDManagerType. Session is maintained by sending a cookie with each request and we cannot use that way for particular reasons.
What I tried: According to some answers to related questions like "sessionId is updated with each request", I tried to fake the session cookie in AuthenticationHandler (I know it's not the proper place but it runs before sessionMiddleware, so..), reading the sessionId from request body, encoding it and setting as a cookie in the Request header:
public class MyAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<MyAuthenticationOptions> {
    public IDataProtector _dataProtector;
    public MyAuthenticationHandler(IDataProtectionProvider dataProtectionProvider, IOptionsMonitor<MyAuthenticationOptions> options, ILoggerFactory logger, UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock) : base(options, logger, encoder, clock) {
        _dataProtector = dataProtectionProvider.CreateProtector(nameof(SessionMiddleware));
    }    

    ....

    string Protect(IDataProtector protector, string data) {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(protector);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(data)) {
            return data;
        }

        var userData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);

        var protectedData = protector.Protect(userData);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(protectedData).TrimEnd('=');
    }

    protected override Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync() {
        // read json from Body into Dictionary of objects
        var data = GetJsonDataIfJson(Request).Result;

        if ( data != null && data.ContainsKey("sessionId") ) {
            string sessionId = (string)data["sessionId"];


            var sessionKey = Protect(_dataProtector, sessionId);
            // not the perfect way ,should be better, but cookie is set
            this.Context.Request.Headers["Cookie"] = "Test_SessionId=" + sessionKey;
        }

        ....
        // always success
        return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket));
    }
}

I've set breakpoint in the SessionMiddleware.cs in the Task Invoke(HttpContext context) and can see that cookie value is read and unprotected successfully, leading to valid sessionKey (the one I got from request and set to cookie) but several lines later, in
feature.Session = _sessionStore.Create(sessionKey, _options.IdleTimeout, _options.IOTimeout, tryEstablishSession, isNewSessionKey);

Although sessionKey is valid, isNewSessionKey == false, tryEstablishSession always returns true and IdleTimeout is several hours - Session.SessionId gets a new value each request, not the one I sent in.
PS: I'm writing some values into the session right after it's initialized, so it's not empty
My 2 questions are:

Why does sessionStore.Create return an object with new sessionId every time?

Is there any other way to achieve the primary goal - maintain session using sessionId value in the request body?


